# how to use import bat

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm new in neo4j.

I'm trying to load csv files using the import.bat,
with shell.
(in windows)
I have 500,000 nodes
and 37 million relationships.

1. The import.bat is not working.
   The code in shell cmd:

   ```
   ../neo4j-community-3.0.4/bin/neo4j-import \ 
   --into ../neo4j-community-3.0.4/data/databases/graph.db \ 
   --nodes:Chain import\entity.csv 
   --relationships import\roles.csv
   ```

   but I did not know where to keep the csv files
   and how to use the import.bat with shell.
   I'm not sure I'm in the right place:

   ```
   neo4j-sh(?)$
   ```

   (I looked at a lot of examples, for me it just does not work)
2. I try to start the server with the cmd line and it's not working. That's what I did:

   ```
   neo4j-community-3.0.4/bin/neo4j.bat start
   ```
3. I want to work with indexes I set the index, but when I try to use it,
   it's not working:

   ```
   start n= node:Chain(entity_id='1') return n;
   ```

   I set the properties:

   ```
   node_keys_indexable=entity_id
   ```

   and also:

   ```
   node_auto_indexing=true
   ```

   Without indexes this query:

   ```
   match p = (a:Chain)-[:tsuma*1..3]->(b:Chain)
   where a.entity_id= 1
   return p;
   ```

   try to get one node with 3 levels

   it's returned 49 relationships in 5 minutes.
   It's a lot of time!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your import command looks correct. You point to the csv files where they are, just like with how you point to `--into` directory. If you're unsure then use fully qualified names like `/home/me/some-directory/entities.csv`. What does it say (really hard to help you without knowing the error).
2. What's the error?
3. Legacy indexes doesn't go well with the importer and so enabling the legacy indexes afterwards doesn't index your data, could you instead use a index (`CREATE INDEX ...`)?

Comment: 1. I tried and it did not work- 
the error:
Unknown command
*the path where the shell.bat and import.bat is:
C:\Users\shaam\neo4j-community-3.0.4\bin\.
* the path of the files to load:
C:\Users\shaam\neo4j-community-3.0.4\import\.
*the target folder to save the data base:
C:\Users\shaam\neo4j-community-3.0.4\data\databases\.

Do I need to set anything in the file properties?

Comment: 2. when I try:
C:\Users\shaam\neo4j-community-3.0.4\bin>neo4j.bat start
I get the error:
WARNING: This command does not appear to be running with administrative rights.
  Some commands may fail e.g. Start/Stop
Invoke-Neo4j : Cannot find any service with service name 'neo4j'.At line:1 char:231

Comment: 3.  from the broser I run this quary:
CREATE INDEX ON :Chain(entity_id);

but when I try:
start n= node:Chain(tik_id='1') return n;
the error is:
Index `Chain` does not exist
(I defined the index before creating the nodes)

Comment: After using `CREATE INDEX`, you can simply query with `MATCH (n:Chain {tik_id = '1'}) RETURN n` or `MATCH (n:Chain) WHERE tik_id = '1' RETURN n` . That `START` syntax is mostly obsolete.

Comment: Oh, you cannot run the import from the (neo4j) shell. It's a separate tool